# Plot axvline using a dataframe column error: ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous.

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, axvline

I am trying to add a horizontal line in a scatter plot based on a column of the dataframe - i got the following error: *ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().*

```
x_line = datLong.groupby('ctr1').agg({'maxx': ['mean']})

for country in datLong.ctr1.unique():
    temp_df = plt.figure(country)
    temp_df = datLong[datLong.ctr1 == country]
    ax1 = temp_df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='Price', color='#d95f0e', label = 'xx', linewidth =3, alpha = 0.7, figsize=(7,4))    
   
    plt.title(country)
    plt.axvline(x=x_line) ### this is the line that is causing this error
 
    plt.show()
print (ax1)
```

The problem seems to be related to the dataframe. But I can figure out what it is? can anybody help me

Comment: `plt.axvline` requires that you pass it a number, but `x_line` is a dataframe.

Comment: thanks, @Swier, I have tried to convert into .numeric but it didn't work (Error: >' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'function'). In this case, I need to have several values (each one corresponding to one country) and the idea is to add the line for each country plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x_line` contains the values for all the countries. With `x_line.loc[country]` you'd get the value for that country. Because it returns an array (of just one element), and `axvline` only accepts single values, you can select its first element (`x_line.loc[country][0]`).

Note that `plt.figure` creates a figure, and pandas plot without the `ax=` parameter also creates a new figure. So, either you should leave out `plt.figure()`, or explicitly create an `ax` to draw on.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

datLong = pd.DataFrame({'ctr1': np.repeat(['country 1', 'country 2'], 20),
                        'x': np.tile(np.arange(20), 2),
                        'maxx': np.random.randn(40) + 10,
                        'Price': np.random.randn(40) * 10 + 200})

x_line = datLong.groupby('ctr1').agg({'maxx': ['mean']})

for country in datLong.ctr1.unique():
    temp_df = datLong[datLong.ctr1 == country]
    ax1 = temp_df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='Price', color='#d95f0e', label='xx', linewidth=3, alpha=0.7,
                       figsize=(7, 4))
    ax1.figure.canvas.set_window_title(country)
    ax1.set_title(country)
    ax1.axvline(x=x_line.loc[country][0])
    plt.show()
```

As `groupby` already creates the dataframes per country, you could rewrite the code making use of `groupby` (without needing `x_line`):

```py
for country, country_df in datLong.groupby('ctr1'):
    ax1 = country_df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='Price', color='#d95f0e', label='xx', linewidth=3, alpha=0.7,
                       figsize=(7, 4))
    ax1.figure.canvas.set_window_title(country)
    ax1.set_title(country)
    ax1.axvline(x=country_df['maxx'].mean())
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Many thanks for the code and for the explanation! It works perfectly!